# How copy selected property (not all) from camel to activiti

Tags: variables, apache-camel, activiti

Camel scenario:

- read file
- do something e.g store content in database
- run activiti process and pass variable from previous step

RouteBuilder:

```
from("file:/home/work/Inbox")
.to("bean:sourceFileService?method=storeFile")
.to("activiti:Receive?copyVariablesFromProperties=true")
```

During call bean sourceFileService property 'sourceFileId' is set.
This variable should be transferred to the process Receive as variable.

If I don't use copyVariablesFromProperties any variable is not set in process.
One the other side when copyVariablesFromProperties=true then camel try pass all properties and exception occurs:

ActivitiException: couldn't find a variable type that is able to serialize GenericFile

(because one of property is object represents read file, there are 7 other unwanted property )

How pass only selected property to activiti endpoint or in camel any next 'to' ?

Answer (score 0):

change `sourceFileService`'s `storeFile` method signature as follows;

```
public String storeFile(... your other params, @OutHeaders Map headers) {
       ...
       headers.put("sourceFileId", "32132132");
       ....
}
```

and you can access the set `sourceFileId` in your `activiti` endpoint

Comment: I have '
    public void storeFile(Exchange exchange) {
    ...
    exchange.setProperty("sourceFileId", "1234"); 
    ...
    } 
    ' 
    This is ok. Ineed know how pass that property as variable for activiti process '.to("activiti:Receive)'

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the use of copyVariablesFromProperties is not necessary.
The same is achieved by

```
.setBody().properties()
.to("activiti:Receive")
```

When in body is Map camel set variables for activiti process using that map.
But I still get exception for the same reason (pass unwanted, not serializable object).

The only solution I have found is

```
from("file:/home/work/Inbox")
.to("bean:sourceFileService?method=storeFile")
.setBody(method(Helper.class))
.to("activiti:Receive")
```

where

```
public class Helper {
    @Handler
    public Map getProcessVariables(Exchange exchange) {
        Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        variables.put("sourceFileId, exchange.getProperty("sourceFileId"));
        return variables;
    }
}
```